# Get back data from ajax JSON ARRAY in php page

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, wordpress, api

I send data in ajax (json array)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/test",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "type":["car"],
    "country": ["Italy", "Canada"],
    "price" : [55 000],
    "colors": ["blue", "black", "red"]
  }),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("success:", data);  // show an empty array
  },
  failure: function(errMsg) {
     console.error("error:",errMsg);
  }
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

When I want to get back data in the php page where I have an sql request
I always get an empty response.

```
function getData() {
    $y = $_POST;
    $array = [];
    $array = array_push($array, $y);
    $j = json_decode($array);
    foreach($j as $k){
        $t = $k->type;
        $c = $k->country;
        $p = $k->price;
        $col = $k->colors;
    }           

    $type = join("','", $t); 
    $country = join("','", $c); 
    $price = join("','", $p); 
    $colors = join("','", $col); 

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE type IN ('$type') AND (country IN ('$country') OR price IN ('$price') OR colors IN ('$price')) ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $result;
}
```

I'd like to get an array like this:

```
'[{"type":["car"], "country": ["Italy", "Canada"], "price" : [55 000], "colors": ["blue", "black", "red"]}]'
```

And then do a json_decode(this array);

Can anyone suggest me how to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Would you care to show us your back-end code?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, do you have any errors in your browser console when you make the AJAX request? You've told $.ajax to expect the response in JSON format, but in your PHP you're not encoding the data as JSON before sending it back. jQuery will choke on that.

Comment: Also check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - there is no "failure" option you can supply to $.ajax. Change it to "error" instead.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting PHP to see the data you're _sending_ to the server, try `$j = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` instead of trying to read from $_POST - this is well documented online if you google how to receive JSON data in PHP.

Comment: Ok. For now it is just a test I will sanitize my code. Right I get  the response: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...   <b>Warning</b>:  join(): Invalid arguments passed in  ...

Comment: Start with the first one. It means probably that what you're passing to foreach is null or is not a loop-able object/array. Which is likely to be because you're not reading the incoming JSON data correctly. Did you implement my suggestion to read it from `php://input` instead?